# Why won't my Edit screen validation allow null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I added a field to a view model for a `Document` that should allow the user to associate it with a `Tenant`. It works fine if the user does assign a tenant, but if they select the null option from the dropdown, then the validation tells me that "The ItemID field is required.", where `ItemID` is a field on `TenantViewModel`.

It occurs to me that perhaps I'm using editor templates wrong - I'm trying to select from a list of tenants, not edit a tenant. If that's wrong, let me know, and maybe suggest a better way to get the dropdown.

```
namespace TenantPortal.Models
{
    public class DocumentViewModel
    {
        ...

        [UIHint("SelectTenant")]
        public TenantViewModel Tenant { get; set; }
     }

    public class TenantViewModel
    {
        private Tenant _ten = null;

        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        public string Display_Name { get; set; }

        public string Legal_Name { get; set; }

        ...
    }
}
```

Editor Template: SelectTenant.cshtml

```
@using CMS.DocumentEngine.Types.Tenantportal
@using TenantPortal.Models
@model TenantViewModel

@{ 
    Layout = null;

    var opts = new SelectList(TenantProvider.GetTenants(), "ItemID", "Display_Name");
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, opts, "(none)")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use data annotations you can add validation to your model.

See my example below:

```
public class TenantViewModel
{
    private Tenant _ten = null;

    [Required]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Display_Name { get; set; }

    public string Legal_Name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

For further information about data annotations [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Also, on your code/controller-action side, you need to use `ModelState.IsValid` check in order to verify whether your model is valid or not

Answer (score 1):

Your `ItemID` field is an `int` so it does not allow null values so the model validation fails.  Try changing it to `int?` (a nullable int).  If a value is not set in the form, then the value will be null, but if a value is selected, the `ItemID` will be the selected value.

Comment: I don't want to change any of the `Tenant` fields with this editor, just select between tenants. I would think setting the Tenant field on `DocumentViewModel` to a nullable type would make sense, except it's already nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding another property to my document view model named `TenantID`, having it communicate with the `Tenant` property behind-the-scenes, and creating SelectLists for `TenantID` dropdowns on both Create and Edit views. It's less elegant than I would like, but it works.